# Vector spaces in terms of polynomials?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I am able to understand when we speak of vectors, what we mean by a vector space and its basis. A basis is the smallest spannable set of vectors that can span the vector space.

But what does it mean for us to talk about a vector space for polynomials? How can we define a basis for a polynomial? The way I think about it polynomials are not vector spaces. They are not arrows with directions and magnitudes.

I know my question is a little naive. But I did not know how else to express my confusion.

Comment: You can add polynomials, there is a $0$ polynomial, you can multiply polynomials by constants and the distributive law holds...that's all you need to make a vector space!

Comment: A vector space is only the abstractisation of the notion of vector: its elements can be added and multiplied by scalars (elements of a field), with the usual  properties. Just like the colour ‘orange’ is the abstractisation of the colour of the eponymous fruit.

Comment: Nothing in the definition of a vector space refers to "arrows" or "directions and magnitudes". And regarding your question about a basis for the space of polynomials, the set $\{ 1,x,x^2,x^3,\ldots \}$ clearly forms a basis.

Comment: In the context, vectors are not necessarily "objects with magnitude and direction".  Instead, a mathematical vector is any set of objects that can be added together and "scaled" (multiplied by a number)

Comment: That should read a mathematical "vector space", not vector

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In physics, vectors are often described as objects with "magnitude and direction".  However, this description does not apply to every object that can be called a vector in the mathematical sense.  Mathematically speaking, a vector space is any set $V$ of objects for which the notions of "addition" (finding $u+v$ for vectors $u,v \in V$) and scaling (finding $ku$ for any number $k$ and vector $v \in V$). We also require that addition and multiplication behave "naturally", which is to say that $V$ satisfies the [vector space axoims](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_space#Definition).

With that said, the set $\mathbb P_n[x]$ of polynomials with degree at most $n$ fits this description. In particular: for two polynomials $p(x),q(x)$, and for any number $k$, we could sensibly compute $p(x) + q(x)$ or $k \cdot p(x)$.

Interestingly, vector spaces can be given an additional structure of "direction". In particular, defining an [inner product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner_product_space) allows us to consider the "angle" between two vectors. This idea is important in Harmonic analysis, where one often makes use of the fact that certain trigonometric polynomials are "orthogonal".